# Implicit conversions and implicit classes

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I wrote the following very simple program which I expected to work fine:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val mc1: MyClass = new MyClass(20);
    val mc2: MyClass = 10
    mc1.doSome //fine
    mc2.doSome //fine
    30.doSome //error. Cannot resolve symbol doSome
  }

  implicit def int2MyClass(i: Int): MyClass = new MyClass(i)

  implicit class Tst(val mc: MyClass){
    def doSome = println(mc.i)
  }
}

class MyClass(val i: Int)
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/12i6Gy)

But unfortunately, it didn't. The error was caused by the implicit conversion failed to convert `30` to `MyClass(30)`. Why? What's wrong with that?

Comment: declare the implicit before the use, if in the same file

Comment: FYI, It compiles by changing `30.doSome` to `(30: MyClass).doSome`. I don't know why! It seems that the compiler applies the implicits once unless you specify the type explicitly.

Comment: As @IdanWaisman has pointed out, Scala doesn't allow stacking/chaining of implicits. It is, by design, a one-and-done mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `30.doSome` Scala compiler looks for the method in `Int` if not found then it looks for the `implicit class` declare on `Int`. But infortunately `implicit class` is declared on `myClass`.

In order to make it work assist the compiler with explicit type

```
(30: MyClass).doSome
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html) might be the issue.